# Create a new NgModule that exports and includes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ng-modules

I'm working on ionic 3. My project is working correctly, but whenever I tried to build an Android release I'm facing this error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image: classes.ts]

[image: classes.module.ts]

[image: app.module.ts]

[image: app.module.ts]

[image: app.component.ts]

Comment: Please do not share error message in images, rather use text for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error, you have declaration of `ClassesPage` in two files(i.e. `app.module.ts` and `classpageModule.ts`). As you are using `lazy-loading`, there is no need to import pages in `app.module.ts`. For this you need to remove/comment `ClassesPage` from `app.module.ts` files `declarations` and `entryComponents` block.

Also it has been observed that, you have added other pages same as that of `ClassesPage`. If `lazy-loading` is there then you need to comment/remove these too from `app.module.ts` file.

Please find detailed description of lazy loading here https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-3-lazy-loading/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ClassesPage` from `app.module.ts`.

> Note : Better keep entire content of your question into the stackoverflow instead of any other reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have added ClassesPage in two modules: AppModule and ClassesPageModule. There are 2 solutions for this:
1.> If you need component in one module only, then only import in that or
2.> Import ClassesPage in a seperate third module, add in declarations and in exports, and then import this third module to both AppModule and ClassesPageModule.

But if I am not wrong, you are only using ClassesPage in ClassesPageModule. So it will be better if you delete ClassesPage from AppModule. Also add ClassesPage to the bootstrap of ClassesPageModule.